# Didn't receive any response from local server in the machine

Tags: networking, nginx, django, docker, uwsgi

So I've server linux using NGIX with docker and many Applications django with UWSGI.

So I need to create a job to execute inside a container of docker. This jobs will do a request to a some url of application django.

However when I tried to make the request I didn't receive any response.

**Command**

```
wget localhost:3031 --bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

**Response:**

```
--2015-09-23 14:20:15--  http://localhost:3031/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:3031... failed: Invalid argument.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3031... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2015-09-23 14:20:16--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:3031/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3031... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2015-09-23 14:20:18--  (try: 3)  http://localhost:3031/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3031... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

**Netstat**

I executed a command to check the application are listing the ports.

```
root@6c9e1bcb238d:/# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

So why i didn't receive any response?

Comment: What is in your config files?